.htaccess 301 redirect parent URL except children URLs
I need to redirect parent URL to new parent URL but children URLs remain same.
www.example.com/blog -> www.example.com/xyx?cat=11

But below URLs remain same for all children URLs
www.example.com/blog/xyz -> www.example.com/blog/xyz

I have tried below solution but children URLs redirect as well
Redirect 301 /blog /xyx?cat=11

My child URL look like below after add above line in .htaccess file
www.example.com/blog/xyz -> www.example.com/xyx?cat=11/xyz

Update:
my .htaccess file look like below:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

    RedirectMatch 302 ^/?blog/?$ /xyz?cat=11
</IfModule>


Don't use Redirect directive for this redirect because Redirect just matches starting part of URI to cause the redirect.
You should use RewriteRule for this to get control of full URI using regular expressions like this:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?blog/?$ /xyx?cat=11 [L,NC,R=302]

This redirect rule will match /blog or /blog/ but will not affect /blog/xyz.
Remember to:

Completely clear your browser cache before testing
Change 302 (temporary redirect) to 301 (permanent redirect) after testing


Thanks for your reply. I have tried above solution but it's not working for me but when I have added RedirectMatch 302 ^/?blog/?$ /xyz?cat=11 then it's working fine for me. Please let me know if anything I missing here. FYI my application is build on Angular 16. Please check my updated question.

This rule will also work if RedirectMatch works fine. Make sure to place my suggested rule just below RewriteBase line.

Sure will try it.

Its working fine when I have added RewriteRule after RewriteBase. Thanks for your help. It's really helpful.
